# What is the difference between yellow and blue lines in test coverage in Xcode 7 ?

Tags: ios, xcode7, test-coverage

I'm just curious what is the difference between those colors in test coverage, I noticed that for 100% it shows blue and for not 100% yellow, but the line length for both is the same sometimes.

Does it indicate anything?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blue Bar :** Indicates the percentage of code coverage. A fully blue bar indicates 100% coverage.

**Orange Bar :** It indicates differences in test coverage between devices.